# Javascript - Create elements using 'surroundContents' breaks when new selection overlaps previously selected text

Tags: javascript, element

I've been working on how to allow visitors to select multiple sections of text wrapped in `<p>` tags to highlight them, and then click a button to remove all highlights.

- Selected text highlights fine with added `classList` to created `<span>` elements.
- If user selects some text that overlaps highlighted text, 
  `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'surroundContents' on 'Range': The Range has partially selected a non-Text node.`
- Removing the `classList` produces fragmented text with empty spans.

I have tried to remove the child elements from the parent, but that removes the original text as well as the tag element.
I think the DOMException is because of the created span tag, but I'm not sure how to remove them when a new selection overlaps.

I have looked at many SO articles, but they seem to focus on JQuery, which I am not using. There is still a lot I do not understand about JavaScript, so MDN has helped a bit, but I sometimes struggle to apply the concepts.

```js
    // HIGHLIGHT SELECTIONS
    const elementToHighlight = document.getElementById('higlight-this');
    elementToHighlight.addEventListener('mouseup', selection);

    function selection() {
      let element = document.createElement('span');
      element.classList.add('hl');
      window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).surroundContents(element);
    }

    // REMOVE hl CLASS
    const removeClassListFromAll = document.getElementById('remove');

    removeClassListFromAll.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let grabHighlighted = document.getElementsByClassName('hl');
      while (grabHighlighted.length) {
        grabHighlighted[0].classList.remove('hl');
        
// grabHighlighted[0].parentElement.removeChild.(grabHighlighted[0]);
      }
    });
```

```css
    .hl {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<section id="higlight-this">
  <p>Some text to test with. Make it look good with highlights!.<br>
    If you don't, It won't be useful for you.</p>
</section>

<button id="remove">remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

the main problem is your selection container is not right try to identify your selection using console.log() and add if else or switch like :

```
  if(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.nodeName == "P")
    window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).surroundContents(element);
    else { //this case when i select from top to bottom with the button
    window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.querySelector("#higlight-this").querySelector("p").getRangeAt(0).surroundContents(element);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, Tarek. I'll try it out, and see how I can extend it to other text elements.

Comment: When you select all text the element container is the "body" so it's showing the because your selection is wrong.... Good luck and happy coding :)

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing the code, error:
```
function selection() {
      let element = document.createElement('span');
      element.classList.add('hl');

      if (window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.nodeName == "P")
        window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).surroundContents(element);
      else { //this case when i select from top to bottom with the button
        window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.querySelector("#higlight-this").querySelector("p").getRangeAt(0).surroundContents(element);
      }
    }
```

Comment: The error is: 
```
TypeError: window.getSelection(...).getRangeAt(...).commonAncestorContainer.querySelector is not a function
```